# the best way to store list inside of a list in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to put a list inside of another list inside of another list in my firebase database, i have this currently in my firebase and my android app, but the app is very slow and i understood from youtube that it's because of the way firebase handles this kind of situations, i lokked up and got nothing on different methodes for storing list inside another list etc..., anyone has better idea of what should i do? 
i know that big apps like spotify is based on google cloud and firebase, and i'm sure that they are using list inside another list in thier firebase, but how can i make it not slow my app down?

here's how i want my firebase database to be, but currently with less lists inside another lists it is very laggy and slows my app down...

[image]

Comment: You don't need to heavily nest your data. For example, comments could be contained in an entirely separate reference, not part of the photo itself.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It sounds like you've already figured out that the deeply nested data is the cause of your app's performance problem. An educated guess (you didn't share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)") is that you're downloading too much data. The solution in that case is to flatten the data, e.g. store the comments in a separate top-level list. There is no magic switch that turns on faster performance for bigger apps, it's all a matter of picking the best data model for your app's use-cases and performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate items in different nodes in Firebase since every `.push()` gives you a a UID.

The way you're doing can be heavy (as you may know) if a user has many pictures with many comments.

If a user pic will have only comments, description, url and likes you can simply put away the comments.

```
user_photos
|_ user_id
|  |_ pic_id
|     |_ url
|     |_ likes
|     |_ description
|     |_ comments_id
pics_comments
|_ pic_id
   |_ comment_id
      |_ text
      |_ user_id
```

Separating more than this is useless since you would need to make another call to firebase just to get some ID or reference. And with this structure it's good since you can query it and get like just the first X pics to show and then use a button where the user can view more or view all and then, if you want, load the comments only when the user scrolls down or click to see comments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried doing it as you said and it works as slow as the old method i used...

Comment: But what part is slow? Getting data? Opening images? Displaying data on your app?